# Perl substitute for white space substitutes at newline also

Tags: regex, perl

I have a text file, its content as follows:

```
a b
c
```

and I use the below Perl code to substitute underscore '-' char at where ever the space char appears in the input line:

```
while (<>) {
   $_ =~ s/\s/_/;
   print $_;
}
```

and I get output like this:

```
a_b
c_
```

So my question is why Perl substitutes underscore in the place of newline '\n' char too which is evident from the input line which contains 'c'? 
When I use **chomp** in the code it works as expected.

Answer (score 10):

`\s` matches all white space chars `[ \t\r\n\f]`, so use space if you want to replace plain spaces

```
$_ =~ s/ /_/g;
# or just
s/ /_/g;
```

Translation could also be used for such simple substitutions, eg. `tr/ /_/;`

Comment: Additionally, the original poster is only changing the first occurrence: he may want 'g' at the end if he wants to change all occurrences in the line.